# OWL API: How to ensure Domain and Range restrictions?

Tags: dns, range, owl, restriction

I try to use the [OWL API](http://owlapi.sourceforge.net/) to create OWL Ontologies. I can define classes, individuals, and relations among them.

When i define an ObjectProperty `#hasPart` with Domain `#A` and Range `#B`, i expected that this property can by applied to individuals of these two classes only. But in fact the API does not care about the restriction, so one can assign `#hasPart` also between two member of class `#C` for example:

```
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.apibinding.OWLManager;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.*;

public class OwlTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    throws org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLOntologyStorageException, org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLOntologyCreationException, Exception
    {
        OWLOntologyManager manager = OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager();
        OWLDataFactory df = manager.getOWLDataFactory();
        OWLOntology o = manager.createOntology();

       //------------------------------------------------------------------

        OWLClass clsA = df.getOWLClass( IRI.create("#A") );
        OWLClass clsB = df.getOWLClass( IRI.create("#B") );
        OWLClass clsC = df.getOWLClass( IRI.create("#C") );

        OWLObjectProperty hasPart = df.getOWLObjectProperty( IRI.create("#hasPart") );
        OWLObjectPropertyDomainAxiom domainAxiom = df.getOWLObjectPropertyDomainAxiom(hasPart, clsA);
        OWLObjectPropertyRangeAxiom   rangeAxiom = df.getOWLObjectPropertyRangeAxiom( hasPart, clsB);

        manager.addAxiom(o, domainAxiom);
        manager.addAxiom(o,  rangeAxiom);

       //------------------------------------------------------------------

        OWLNamedIndividual a1 = df.getOWLNamedIndividual( IRI.create("a1") );
        OWLNamedIndividual b1 = df.getOWLNamedIndividual( IRI.create("b1") );
        OWLNamedIndividual c1 = df.getOWLNamedIndividual( IRI.create("c1") );
        OWLNamedIndividual c2 = df.getOWLNamedIndividual( IRI.create("c2") );

        manager.addAxiom(o, df.getOWLClassAssertionAxiom(clsA, a1));
        manager.addAxiom(o, df.getOWLClassAssertionAxiom(clsB, b1));
        manager.addAxiom(o, df.getOWLClassAssertionAxiom(clsC, c1));
        manager.addAxiom(o, df.getOWLClassAssertionAxiom(clsC, c2));

        manager.addAxiom(o, df.getOWLObjectPropertyAssertionAxiom(hasPart, c1, c2));   // ObjectProperty '#hasPart' should only work for objects from Domain 'clsA' and Range 'clsB'

       //------------------------------------------------------------------

        manager.saveOntology(o, IRI.create("file:/tmp/data.owl"));
    }
}
```

Output `/tmp/data.owl`:

```
...
    <ObjectProperty rdf:about="#hasPart">
        <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="#A"/>
        <rdfs:range rdf:resource="#B"/>
    </ObjectProperty>

    <Class rdf:about="#A"/>
    <Class rdf:about="#B"/>
    <Class rdf:about="#C"/>

    <NamedIndividual rdf:about="a1">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="#A"/>
    </NamedIndividual>

    <NamedIndividual rdf:about="b1">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="#B"/>
    </NamedIndividual>

    <NamedIndividual rdf:about="c1">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="#C"/>
        <p1:hasPart rdf:resource="c2"/>
    </NamedIndividual>
...
```

I'm now looking for the recommended way to deal with this kinds of restrictions programmatically..? Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there's nothing wrong with using hasPart w/ C, the reasoner will just assume that you'll eventually tell it that c1 is also an A, or that C is the same as A.

OWL-API isn't going to enforce the behavior you want, it sounds like you're looking for some sort of integrity constraints like you'd get in a normal relational system.  You'll either have to bake that into your application or look into something like Pellet's [integrity constraints](http://clarkparsia.com/pellet/icv/) which will be available in the upcoming Pellet 3 release and is currently available in [Stardog](http://stardog.com).

Comment: This answer from Michael is correct, however, it doesn't solve the modeling issue.

The solution for your case: make all three classes disjunct.

That tells the system, that things, that are in one class, cannot be in any of the other classes.

That way, your code would work like you expect it.